# VSTO C# Excel add-in is not showing the name

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

I created an Excel Add-in in Visual Studio using C#, and it seems that the Tab Name is not showing.
Disabling and enabling the add-in solves the issue, but it's not something that I can ask my customers to do... And if I close Excel I need to do the enable trick all over again.
I tried changing the Tab ID, maybe it was to generic, did not work.
Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do for the Tab Name to show?

As the file opened:
[image]

After disabling and enabling:
[image]

Comment: Did you use the ribbon designer or ribbon XML for the custom UI? What is your ribbon XML?

Comment: Was this on a test installation or your dev machine? I have seen it go blank because I was doing a test addin, and my original addin went blank. I don't believe that this will affect your customers and is localized to your dev machine.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear and etc. Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) article.

Also it makes sense to use a `getLabel` callback for the ribbon tab. In that case you will be able to debug the code and see what is going on under the hood. Read more about the Ribbon UI (Fluent UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)